# The set of functions that are one except in a finite set is countable

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I have to prove the following:

Let $X \subset F ( \mathbb{N}; \mathbb{N} ) $ be the set of all functions equal to 1 for all points except in a finite set $A$. Prove that $X$ is countable.

I have thought about using the set $P_f = \cup_{n \in  \mathbb{N} }P_n$ with $P_n = \{A \subset  \mathbb{N} / |A| = n\}$ and define a function $\phi : P_f \longrightarrow X$ that gives $\phi (A)=f_A$ but I'm not sure as to how to prove that $\phi$ is well defined.

I'm also told that Cantor's Theorem plays a part in this proof, but I really don't see how...

Answer (score 1):

Such a function is uniquely determined by the set $A$ on which it does not take the value $1$, and the values it takes on $A$.

First, show that there are countably many finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$.  (Let $F$ be the set of finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$.  A one-to-one correspondence with $\mathbb{N}$ is given by $S\mapsto\sum_{s\in S} 2^s$, where I take $0\in \mathbb{N}$.)

Next, show that the number of functions from a finite set $A$ to $\mathbb{N}$ is countable.  The number of such functions is $\aleph_0^{\mid A\mid}=\aleph_0$.

Since a countable union of countable sets is countable, you are done.

I don't see how to do this with Cantor's theorem.